# How to find all key terms that collaborated papers between Term A and B?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can I write an SQL query to form a three-column list of Term A (Term), Term B (Term), and the number of collaborated papers between Term A and B. I am using MySQL Server with MYSQL Workbench.

Schema:

```
AreaFocus(
         Term,
         Scale,
         Paper_ID
);
```

Sample Table Data:

| Term | Scale | Paper_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Technology | 0.122 | 313 |
| Science | 0.222 | 313 |
| Computer science | 0.333 | 458 |
| Science | 0.112 | 458 |
| Technology | 0.123 | 458 |
| Science | 0.331 | 419 |
| Technology | 0.332 | 419 |
| Computer science | 0.333 | 619 |
| Data Science | 0.334 | 619 |
| Technology | 0.334 | 619 |

Expected Result:

| Term A | Term B | Joint Papers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Technology | Science | 3 |
| Technology | Computer science | 2 |
| Science | Computer science | 1 |
| Computer science | Data Science | 1 |
| Technology | Data Science | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

The key to solving this is to join the table to itself such that we don't select both Technology|Science and Science|Technology. We do this by using `<` or `>` in the term join condition.

```
select af1.term as term_a, af2.term as term_b, count(*) as joint_papers
from areafocus af1
join areafocus af2 on af2.paper_id = af1.paper_id and af2.term > af1.term
group by af1.term, af2.term
order by af1.term, af2.term;
```